# Unexpected dabbrev-expand forward completion behavior

Tags: completion, dabbrev

Given a buffer containing `a abc` with point immediately following the first `a`,

```
 ↓
a abc
```

if I perform forward completion with `(dabbrev-expand -1)`, it produces the result I would expect:

```
   ↓
abc abc
```

But given a buffer containing `aabc` with point immediately following the first `a`,

```
 ↓
aabc
```

I would expect forward completion to produce:

```
   ↓
abcabc
```

Instead, it produces:

```
    ↓
aabcabc
```

Is this a bug, or a misunderstanding on my part?

Answer (score 1):

This is on account of `dabbrev--search`.  In your case, the `pattern` values are your `"a"` prefix followed by word/symbol-constituent characters, and `reverse` is `nil`.

```el
        [...]
        ;;--------------------------------
        ;; Look for a distinct expansion, using dabbrev--last-table.
        ;;--------------------------------
        (while (and (not found-string)
                    (if reverse
                        (re-search-backward pattern1 nil t)
                      (re-search-forward pattern1 nil t)))
          (goto-char (match-beginning 0))
          ;; In case we matched in the middle of a word,
          ;; back up to start of word and verify we still match.
          (dabbrev--goto-start-of-abbrev)

          (if (not (looking-at pattern1))
              nil
            ;; We have a truly valid match.  Find the end.
            (re-search-forward pattern2)
            (setq found-string (match-string-no-properties 0))
            (setq result found-string)
            [...]
```

So it finds a match for `a`, backs up to the start of the word, still matches `a` (now a different one), and grabs the word as the completion.

Comment: And this might arguably be a bug, although I've not checked the docs.  Perhaps `dabbrev--goto-start-of-abbrev` should be bounded by the initial position of point in this scenario.